# Not able to get public ip for ec2-instance via boto3 python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to fetch ec2 information via python program , but i am not able to get value for public ip address..which printing as None though it has public ip attached to it (i can see from console)

What I tried:

```
inst_id = []
for reserv in res_inst['Reservations']:
    instance = reserv['Instances']
    for inst in instance:
        ip_addr = inst['PrivateIpAddress']
        #print(inst)
        if (ip == ip_addr):
            inst_id = inst['InstanceId']
            inst_type = inst['InstanceType']
            image_id = inst['ImageId']
            vpc_id = inst['VpcId']
            key_name = inst['KeyName']
            #pub_ip = inst[u'PublicIpAddress']
            pub_ip = inst.get(u'PublicIpAddress')
            print(inst_type)
            print(inst_id)
            print(key_name)
            print(vpc_id)
            print(pub_ip)
            print(image_id)
            az = inst['Placement']['AvailabilityZone']
            print(az)
            for s1 in inst['SecurityGroups']:
                sg_name = s1['GroupName']
                print(sg_name)
```

In above code, these syntaxes are not working for public ip..its says key error

```
pub_ip = inst[u'PublicIpAddress']
pub_ip = inst['PublicIpAddress']
```

The below syntax works, but giving None as value

```
pub_ip = inst.get(u'PublicIpAddress')
```

Output: I am getting all values except print(pub_ip) which is printing as None.

I am sure when i printing whole json string of `inst` in above code, i see public ip value present in that json dictionary, however, when printing its saying None.

Can any one suggest what wrong thing i am doing here ...

Comment: It could be really none. When the ec2 locates in the private subnet, it will not have the public one.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Hi asp, 
Please try this...

```
response= ec2_client.describe_instances()
for reservation in response['Reservations']:            
   for instance in reservation['Instances']:
      print(instance)
```

Hope it helps..
@r0ck